# I have a Recycler View, onRun will display, but upon a button click it will be empty, I want to set a default recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I currently have a recycler view that works off Latitude and Longitude within Android studio. On load due to using an emulator i pass a default location, this loads areas around the location within a map. I also have a spinner which allows you to change area and display markers on a map on screen. However the problem is when the Location which in my case is the current location (set to default emulator location Google Pixel San Francisco?) is used, the recycler view shows as empty, i want to edit my recycler view within my Adapter class so that IF the view is empty set the text to "No places around you" if code needed please ask.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        QuietPlace quietPlace = mQuietPlace.get(position);
        if (mQuietPlace.size() > 0){
            TextView textView = holder.titleTextView;
        textView.setText(quietPlace.getName());
        TextView textView2 = holder.noiseTextView;
        textView2.setText(quietPlace.getNoise());
        TextView textView3 = holder.distanceTextView;
        textView3.setText(String.valueOf(quietPlace.getDistance()));
        }
        else {
            TextView textViewEmpty = holder.titleTextView;
            textViewEmpty.setText("No Quiet Places near your location");
            TextView textViewEmpty2 = holder.noiseTextView;
            textViewEmpty2.setText(" ");
            TextView textViewEmpty3 = holder.distanceTextView;
            textViewEmpty3.setText(" ");
        }
    }
```

Edit:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class QuietPlaceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuietPlaceAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<QuietPlace> mQuietPlace;

    public QuietPlaceAdapter(List<QuietPlace> quietPlaces)
    {
        mQuietPlace = quietPlaces;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View quietPlaceView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(quietPlaceView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        QuietPlace quietPlace = mQuietPlace.get(position);

        TextView textView = holder.titleTextView;
        textView.setText(quietPlace.getName());
        TextView textView2 = holder.noiseTextView;
        textView2.setText(quietPlace.getNoise());
        TextView textView3 = holder.distanceTextView;
        textView3.setText(String.valueOf(quietPlace.getDistance()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mQuietPlace.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView titleTextView;
        public TextView noiseTextView;
        public TextView distanceTextView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            titleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quietPlaceTitle);
            noiseTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quietPlaceNoise);
            distanceTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quietPlaceDistance);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks good, so, what do you want to do?And can u post the whole adapter file?

Comment: I read the sqlite database, if it returns "Quiet Places" around your coordinates, I display them within a recycler view, and tell you the distance and noise the levels. However, I have "Quiet Places" created for only certain Coordinates, so when I select coordinates that my database has no results for, I want to just display an empty Recycler View with text stating that there is no "Quiet Places" near ur coordinates. I will add Adapater file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the list in constructor if it is dynamic.

Add this function in your adapter

```
public void setPanelList(List<QuietPlace> quietPlaces){

    mQuietPlace = quietPlaces;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In activity, setPanelList(quietPlaces) when your `quietPlaces` changed.

```
quietPlaceAdapter.setPanelList(quietPlaces)
```

Hope this helps.